# Implementing nested templated functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class inside a templated class. I can easily implement the member functions inline, but in my specific case I'm running into forward declare problems, so forced to implement it after the declaration -- and I realize I've forgotten how to do so.

If this small example can be made to compile (without moving the definition inline) my question will be answered:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename V>
struct Outer {

    template <int Count>
    struct Inner {
        void printer() const;
    };

};

template <typename T, typename V, int Count>
inline void Outer<T, V>::Inner<Count>::printer() const {
    std::cout << "Oh hai. I'm inner<" << Count << ">" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Outer<int, int>::Inner<3> i;

    i.printer();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Fixed the unrelated typos that Stuart fix (to help make the answer more clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiles and works for me with g++ 4.2.1. (It also compiles with the online Comeau compiler, for what it's worth.) The key changes are (a) consistently spelling `Outer` correctly, (b) separating out the two sets of template parameters, and (c) changing `Counter` to `Count`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename V>
struct Outer {

    template <int Count>
    struct Inner {
        void printer() const;
    };

};

template <typename T, typename V>
template <int Count>
void Outer<T, V>::Inner<Count>::printer() const {
    std::cout << "Oh hai. I'm inner<" << Count << ">" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Outer<int, int>::Inner<3> i;

    i.printer();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry about those typos (it's a bit hard to notice when intentionally making code that doesn't compile)

Comment: No probs, glad I could help :)